# Fancybox does not work fine

Tags: jquery, html

my fancybox code does not work when I add the following script in the body. What's the problem here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#example4").fancybox({
        'opacity'       : true,
        'overlayShow' : false,
        'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'none'
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" Src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <a id='example4' href='./example/4_b.jpg'>Image</a>

    <!--WHEN I ADD THIS LINES-->
    <!-------------------------------------------->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------------------->
</body>
```

Comment: Sure that `<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>` is load

Comment: Check your developer console for errors and post them. And why would you load jQuery twice, one of which is the ancient 1.4 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the issues is that you are including jQuery twice, once in the `<head>` section and once in the `<body>` section. You should include it only once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <a id='example4' href='./example/4_b.jpg'>Image</a>

    <!--WHEN I ADD THIS LINES-->
    <!-------------------------------------------->
    <!-- <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------------------->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue was i was using an old version of jQuery, so a few features it weren't.